# Android SQLite get youngest person from database

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I have a Person object that I store in a SQLite database.

Person has Age, FirstName, and LastName.

At a given moment, I want to find the youngest person (lowest Age).

How can I do this?

So far I have this:

```
public Person getYoungest(Cursor c) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        db.rawQuery("SELECT MIN(" + AGE + ") FROM " + PERSON_TABLE, null);
        // Person youngestPerson = ???
        // return youngestPerson;
}
```

However, I'm really confused at what the "rawQuery" does. It doesn't return a person object. Also, I'm not sure whether the query gives me the lowest "age", or the record containing the lowest "age" (which is what I want). I'm very new to SQL, so this is all strange to me.

Any advice?

Comment: your username is ... unusual.

Comment: Since your question is very basic you should really take a SQL tutorial first.

Comment: I am confused more at how I translate the query into a Java object.

Comment: Then you should take an Android SQLite tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite returns strings, numbers, byte arrays.

They are not like java-objects. You have to retrieve your each value and initialize your person in the code using a constructor.

Or use realm database that easily helps to store java-objects using sqlite.

do not forget to improve the performance by using

```
SELECT * FROM ... LIMIT 1
```

like Marcin Orlowski said.

to retrieve the data use this:

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");
        int nameColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
        int emailColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("email");

 int id = c.getInt(idColIndex) 
          String name =    c.getString(nameColIndex) 
          String email   =  c.getString(emailColIndex)
```

to create an object use this:

```
new Person(<your values>);
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it did the best job addressing my problem.

Answer (score 2):

What you are currently doing is querying for smallest age value from your dataset. If you want to get the whole data row of such you need to use `ORDER BY`, like

```
SELECT * FROM ... ORDER BY age ASC LIMIT 1
```

which would sort the data by Age in ascending order. As you want just one we use `LIMIT` to ensure this is going that way (and to make things faster), yet note that most likely many records may have the same age (incl. lowest value) so you may extend `ORDER BY` to fine tune sorting.

Comment: Thanks! So, even if I did that, how would I retrieve the Person object from the result?

Comment: you do not have object in database. Just values. So you most likely need to build your object based on values from your DB. And I strongly recommend you go thru sqlite db tutorial first as you seem to be doing things blindly.

Answer (score 0):

db.rawQuery ==> return a Cursor which point to the returned data from select statement so you should make

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM PERSON_TABLE ORDER BY age ASC , null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) //mean find data and point to the samllest
cursor.getString(c.getColumnIndex("field_name"));
```